# Really what is event in Threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, pthreads, definition

Thread is formally a sequence of events.
Some of the events mentioned below

- Assign to a shared variable
- Assign to a local variable
- Invoke method
- Return from method

So here, It means instruction execution and events are the same or not.

I need to know the difference between the event and instruction execution if they are different?

Can anyone explain what is called an event?

Threads and these events can be seen as state diagrams where threads (programming counter, local variables) are states and events are transitions.
**Whenever an event happens thread state may change.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those don't look like events to me.

Comment: Did I misunderstand event @RobertHarvey

Comment: Apparently so.  ...

Comment: Perhaps go back to your definition of "thread".  I'm not sure where that came from, but I suspect that non-idiomatic use of the term "event" int it may be tangential to the underlying question.

Comment: Re, "Did I misunderstand event?" I think we are mixing up ideas from distinct realms of knowledge here. "Event" means something different in a computer science context from what it means to software engineers. Your descriptions of "events" and "threads" sounds like they belong to a high-level, abstract, formal discussion of what we can possibly know about threads; but some of the people who are answering appear to interpret those same words from the perspective of a software developer trying to solve some concrete problem using libraries/tools that assign very specific meaning to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal event is an instruction execution. External event is a mean of communication between threads. They are implemented by special kinds of instructions, which can safely be executed on parallel threads (CAS, compare-and-set, compare-and-swap). The ulimate goal of external event is to pass signal from one thread to another. Usually it is done using a buffer, that is, one thread puts signal in a buffer, and another thread extracts that signal, waithing if no signals are ready.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexei, As you said, the external event is a special kind of instruction execution but these instructions are used to pass the signal from one thread to another.

Comment: External events and  Internal events are differentiated with their goals but both are instruction execution. Did I got your point?@Alexei

Comment: ultimately, everything what happens in computer is execution of instructions. But this approach is too low-lewel, and usually more large building blocks are used - procedure calls, critical sections, etc.